# react-native pod install (C compiler cannot create executables)

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm trying to setup a new react native project on my Mac (M1).

After initing the project with `npx react-native init test` I get the output:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./test/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

I then run `pod install` and get this error:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/aast/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-73c24/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/aast/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-73c24/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/aast/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-73c24':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I've tried multiple solutions, including resetting xcode-select, making sure the cli tools for xcode are set, and disabling Flipper in the Podfile, but none of them worked for me.

Note I did not make any changes to the project, I am getting an error on a new, clean react native project

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the following command to make this work

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: This worked for me! 

Can you explain why this works? What does this command do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem caused by the new processor architecture. Please try to start the terminal with Rosetta and then try the steps again.
Start Terminal with Rosetta:

1. Right-click on Terminal in Finder
2. Get Info
3. Open with Rosetta